# Find 2nd order recurrence relation with given solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $(a)_{n\geq0}$ with $a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}$ and $a_0=1, a_1=4$.

The sequence $(b)_{n\geq0}$ shall satisfy $$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_k$$

I have to find a 2nd order recurrence relation which has $(b_n)_{n\geq0}$ as solution. How does one approach this task?

I first solved the recurrence realtion for $(a_n)$:

$$a_n=\frac{6\cdot3^n+(-1)^{n+1}2^n}{5}$$

But how do I proceed?

Comment: Now that you know $a_k$ you can substitute it in the sum and calculate $b_n$. You'll get a sum of two powers, which can be written as a second order recurrence.

Comment: You realize you can find a closed form for $ b_{n} $ without the need of a $ 2^{\text{nd}} $ order recurrence relation, but using the binomial theorem instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $n \geq 0$, one has
\begin{align*} b_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{6\cdot3^k+(-1)^{k+1}2^k}{5}\\
&=\frac{6}{5}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}3^k  - \frac{1}{5}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-2)^k\\
&=\frac{6}{5}(3+1)^n  - \frac{1}{5}(1-2)^n\\
&=\frac{6 \cdot 4^n - (-1)^n}{5}\\
\end{align*}

which satisfies the recursion
$$\boxed{b_{n+2} = 3b_{n+1} + 4b_n}$$

Comment: Thanks! How did you find out the recursion it satisfies?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it